# Are there any Industry Analysts that participate in the Stack Overflow Community?

Tags: discussion, users

If there aren't, would members of the community find value in their offerings? If they do participate, what types of projects/expertise are they currently contributing?

Comment: This should be asked on meta.

Comment: What do you mean by an "industry analyst"? I doubt that StackOverflow would provide any useful and non-anecdotal information for someone who is not a practicing engineer, researcher, or educator.

Comment: And who exactly qualifies as an 'Industry Analyst'?

Comment: @Kelly: Maybe I qualify. Like many I've pontificated ignorantly and at length on slashdot, so the description **must** fit…

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are.

Comment: You must be one: answer is absolutely true, even answers fully what the OP asked for, as you have well analysed this as a closed question - at least the title, then you left an unfinished job after doing the high level stuff by not answering the questions in the body, and the answer is absolutely useless.